# C Macro for including function

Tags: c++, c, macros, arduino

I want to depending on a #define'd value run a certain code. To clarify my situation, I have some code posted below. Now, for example `#define VALUE 0` is done. This can be any number. IF the value is equal to 0, the first for loop should run, otherwise it shouldn't. I have used `#ifdef VALUE` before, but VALUE is always defined and I need to check the real value it has. Is it possible with macros, to speed up the code?

```
#define VALUE 0
void hardwareDIO::readDI(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    for(byte ii = 0; ii < 8; ii++){
      if(bitRead(_DIDirect[i], ii)){
        bitWrite(_hwStatDir[i], ii, !digitalRead(8*i+ii));
      }
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    if(_extenderNrs[i] == -1){
      break;
    }else{
      for(byte ii = 0; ii < 2; ii++){
        byte values = 0;
        if(ii == 0){
          values = expanderRead(_extenderNrs[i], GPIOA);
        }else{
          values = expanderRead(_extenderNrs[i], GPIOB);
        }
        for(byte iii = 0; iii < 8; iii++){
          if(bitRead(_arrayIO[i][ii], iii)){  // input detected
            bitWrite(_hwStatIO[i][ii], iii, !bitRead(values, iii));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `#if VALUE`?

Comment: C++ or C? 2 different languages.

Comment: I can't spot any usage of `VALUE` in your code?!?

Comment: The `VALUE` is used in other c files. C/C++ hybrid, it's Arduino. And `#if VALUE` will skip if VALUE is 0, like a normal if statement?

Comment: `#if VALUE` will skip if VALUE is 0 or undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
#if VALUE==1
....
#endif
```

Rather than

```
#ifdef VALUE
```

Syntax should be obvious from here - pick any value (even zero) to compile that block of code.

Comment: `#if VALUE`, as suggested by Brian, is terser.

Comment: But #if VALUE tells you whether it is zero or non-zero. It doesn't allow you to select for _any_ value